# CERT-like Secure Coding standards for C#

Tags: c#, secure-coding

I am still fairly new to the C# world compared to my experience with C++ and I am currently wondering, if there is anything on secure coding rules / best practices / coding guidelines for C# apart from the very short list provided by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/security/secure-coding-guidelines

For C, C++, Java and Perl there is CERT:
https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/seccode

and I would really like to know, if there is at least something comparable. I guess, that some of the basics will still apply (things like "don't divide by 0" or "don't cause ints to wrap") - but I was hoping to find something more specific to C# and .NET.

Comment: Yes. A *lot*, even in MSDN itself. There are entire subsites related to security. You just landed on a single page. This question is far too broad to be answered in SO

Comment: BTW the CERT guides themselves are **way** too short. Most breaches are caused eg by SQL injection, script injection, malicious input. Leaked credentials. Insecure password storage. Applications running using admin accounts. You'll find sections on Security for every stack or feature in MSDN, eg for Winfoms, WPF, ASP.NET (a *lot* of stuff there).

Comment: Check the [Awesome Security](https://github.com/guardrailsio/awesome-dotnet-security) site for some pointers to code analyzers, security-related guides and articles. You'll notice that the majority of issues aren't language specific.

Comment: Also check the [Secure Development Lifecycle](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/securityengineering/sdl) at Microsoft, which goes beyond simple rule to the entire process of developing secure software.

Comment: I'll agree that finding all that is a pain though - it should be possible to just find a section in `learn.microsoft.com` under the `.NET` site, not google around for 30 minutes